# Z3: Offering random solutions in solving

Tags: z3

I tried the following code in `http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial`

```
(declare-const a Int)
(assert (> a 100))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

the result is always `a=101`. I need some randomness in the answer that it produce a random number in the range `[101,MAXINT)`. for example gets a `seed=1000` and offers the `a=12344`. for `seed=2323` offers `a=9088765` and ... .

what should i add to this simple code?

Answer (score 4):

The linear arithmetic solver is based on the Simplex algorithm. So, the solutions will not be random.
The bit-vector solver is based on SAT, you can get "random" solutions by encoding your problem in bit-vector arithmetic and selecting random phase selection. Here is an example (also available [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/vu9I)):

```
(set-option :auto-config false)
(set-option :phase-selection 5) ;; select random phase selection
(declare-const a (_ BitVec 32))
(assert (bvugt a (_ bv100 32))) ;; a > 100 as a bitvector constraint
(check-sat)
(get-model)
;; try again
(check-sat)
(get-model)
;; try again
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```