# Use of random-seeds in Z3

Tags: z3

What is the use of the option random-seed in z3? Can it be used to generate random models? In this post [Z3: Offering random solutions in solving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770582/z3-offering-random-solutions-in-solving), it is mentioned that LIA cant have random models. So why do we need random-seeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use random seeds to control the propositional variable selection heuristic in the SMT core. Random seeds can among other things be used to check if the performance of the SAT search component is stable under pertubations in the order of how the formula is written.

Comment: Thanks Nikolaj for the answer. One thing is for sure, for LIA we can't get random models. But for bit-vectors how does phase-selection works, and can we get different models each time we execute using different random-seeds. And also what is the range of random-seed values that Z3 can accept.